# Checking if a variable contains a name and at least a digit from a surname

Tags: php, validation

I would like to check if at least a digit was inserted after the first name in this input.

So, if the user input 'joe' it will not validate, but 'joe d' or 'joe doe' it will pass.

How can this be done?

```
$nome = $this->coalesce($form['nome']);
if (strlen($nome) > 0)
    $this->setValue('nome', strtoupper($nome));
else
    $this->addError('nome', 'Invalid name!');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to do this:

```
if( preg_match( '/\w+ \w+/', $name)) {
    echo "Validation passes!";
} else { 
    echo "Invalid input";
}
```

You can change the regex to `'/[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+/'`, since `\w` will match more than just alphabetic characters (it includes numbers and underscores).

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do it:

```
if(!preg_match('/[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+/i', $nome)) {
    $this->addError('nome', 'Invalid name!');
}
```

This will validate names that consist of a string of alphabetic characters, followed by a space then another alphabetic string.